# differentiate wrt time

Tags: derivatives, differential

I came across these equations in a mechanics textbook and wish to differentiate the first equation  w.r.t. time to obtain that second equation. Any help is much appreciated!

$c(f_1+f_2)=a^2(\frac{1}{2}\dot{a}^2 -ca+h)+2af'_2$

$c(1-\frac{\dot{a}}{c})(f'_1+f'_2)=ca(-2\dot{a}^2 (1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{a}}{c})-a\ddot{a}(1-\frac{\dot{a}}{c})+2\frac{\dot{a}}{c}h+\frac{a}{c}\dot{h})+2a(1+\frac{\dot{a}}{c}){f''_2}$

Here: $f_1(x)=f_1(t-r/c)$ and $f_2(x)=f_1(t+r/c)$

The book didn't explicitly state the functions of time, but from the second equation we can see that $a$ and $h$ are all functions of time.

We also know that $\frac{f'_1+f'_2}{a}+\frac{1}{2}\dot{a}^2+h=0$ (if that's of any help)

I tried doing it a few times and this is all I get:

$$c(\dot{f_1}+\dot{f_2})=a\dot{a}^2+a^2\dot{a}-3ca^2+\dot{h}a^2+2ha+2\dot{a}{f'_2}+2a\dot{f'_2}$$

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thanks

Comment: OK, this is what's happening. Note that the equation has been differentiated twice at least, not once as you have just done. So do it once again and see what happens.

Comment: @Allawonder why does $c$ change with time?

Comment: That was ill-timed.

Comment: @Allawonder so I just tried differentiating it once more, but I get $f'''_2$ in the last term which isn't in the second equation.

Comment: Finally, I think they must have combined the derivative with the initial equation to obtain the second one above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: Some variable might have been eliminated between the first equation and its derivative to obtain the second equation.

Comment: @Allawonder ya most probably, but I am trying to figure out how exactly they got the second equation...

Comment: I could have verified this, but I'm loath to do the computations by hand. On a good day I could tackle it, but I couldn't be bothered to do that in my present circumstances. But you could check it out.

Comment: One way is to simplify their final equation as much as possible, then see how it could have resulted as suggested.